# centOS 6.5 i386 Minimal Installation Ends with Arrow of Black Background

Tags: centos

I am installing centOS 6.5 for i386 using Minimal installation.  I boot up computer with the disk and choose

```
install or upgrade an existing system
```

Everything proceeds without any errors but it ends with a white, hollow (cursor) arrow on a black background and doesn't go any further.  I can move the arrow around with my mouse but I left the computer for over an hour and, when I come back, it's the same thing.  Just a white, hollow arrow on a black background.

The first time I ran it through, I selected the (default) option to check the hardware for suitability.  It ran and said that the hardware was fine but ejected the disk.  I read that this was a type of bug so I rebooted again, followed the same procedure as before and chose continue w/o checking the hardware.  The installation seemed to be running fine but ended with the white arrow on the black background and did not go any further.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by rebooting and choosing the second option: "Install system with basic video driver".